# Detect if a Player is Moving or Not while touching part (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

Heres my code(Not working)

```
workspace.corridor.Monster.EyeHitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local Character = game.StarterPlayer.StarterCharacterScripts

    Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Running:Connect(function(speed)
        if speed > 0.1 then -- Walking
            print("Walking")
        else -- Idle
            print("Standing")
        end
    end)
end)
```

My code doesnt work, can someone explain why and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```lua
workspace.corridor.Monster.EyeHitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    local Humanoid = hit.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    if Humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 then
        plr:Kick("Dont move")
    else
        print("Player survived")
    end
end)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Humanoid:GetPropertyChangedSignal("MoveDirection"):Connect(function()
print(Humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude)
end)

Comment: still not working